# Get youtube and Vimeo thumbnails same size

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, youtube, vimeo

I have a list of VideoID's from youtube and vimeo and I want to show the thumbnails in a list.

The problem is that vimeo allows only 3 sizes: small, medium, large and youtube also 3: default, mq, hq. But no size from youtube thumbnail matches with a vimeo thumnbail.

```
<videos> 
  <video> 
    [skipped]
    <thumbnail_small>http://ts.vimeo.com.s3.amazonaws.com/235/662/23566238_100.jpg</thumbnail_small> 
    <thumbnail_medium>http://ts.vimeo.com.s3.amazonaws.com/235/662/23566238_200.jpg</thumbnail_medium> 
    <thumbnail_large>http://ts.vimeo.com.s3.amazonaws.com/235/662/23566238_640.jpg</thumbnail_large> 
    [skipped]
</videos>
```

youtube gives me:

```
      [skipped]
      <media:thumbnail url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/jXE6G9CYcJs/default.jpg'
        height='90' width='120' time='00:01:41' yt:name='default'/>
      <media:thumbnail url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/jXE6G9CYcJs/hqdefault.jpg'
        height='360' width='480' yt:name='hqdefault'/>
      <media:thumbnail url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/jXE6G9CYcJs/mqdefault.jpg'
        height='180' width='320' yt:name='mqdefault'/>
      <media:thumbnail url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/jXE6G9CYcJs/1.jpg'
        height='90' width='120' time='00:00:50.500' yt:name='start'/>
      [skipped]
```

I would like to show the list of videos with all the thumnails being the same size. (I have a specific size from my designers)
How do you suggest I should go for it?

Answer (score 0):

I fudged it by using Vimeo's "thumbnail_large" which is 640px wide, then I took YouTube's "mqdefault" and set a width of 640 on my image tag. This scales it up, which looks kinda low quality, but I'm dealing with a responsive framework... on the desktop, the thumbnails will fit into a smaller grid with more across (and look fine) but on phones or small tablets, they will stack and at least they will all be the same width. I may tweak it a bit more, but that's how I hacked it for now. YMMV!

Comment: I did the same thing, but I was hoping there are better thing that could be done